# How to Securely Get the Data from a Select Form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, e-commerce

I am Building an Ecommerce Platform and Using the Form with Select to Get the Required Size of T-shirt and Many other Things on the Platform.
I am Facing the Issue that I am Using event object to handle the Submit Data Flow to the Function.

```
<form onChange={this.handleAtbChange}>
    <label for="size">Size</label>
    <select name="size" id="size">
        <option value='default' selected>Size</option>
        <option value='L'>L</option>
        <option value='XL'>XL</option>                      
    </select>
</form>
```

What if the User Directly Modifies the Value of the Option in the Select through the Developer Console?
This will Break my Whole Application when I Try to send random size name to the Server.

What will be the Best Solution to this Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side validation is meant for usability, not security. The best way is to never trust what's coming from the client-side. You are right about users can directly modify input values in developer console. In fact, they can do more than that.

Perform validation in the back-end server and send error response back to the client accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Server side validation will handle this. Return the page back to the form if the input values is empty or different than expected.